# lighweight wavefront obj model parser

Tags: graphics, wavefront

I am looking for a lightweight c++ wavefront obj parser.   In addition, I need the following capabilities:

1. Join the adjacent planar triangles to form polygons.
2. Read the curves as well from obj file

I have considered glm and assimp, but they do not provide the above things.
Could someone please suggest something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try libg3d if you are using Linux.